# Do sets have all their members necessarily? [Set theory and modal logic]

Tags: modal-logic

Can there be two possible worlds $w_1$ and $w_2$, an object $o$ (set or not) and a set $s$, such that $o\in s$ is true in $w_1$, $o\notin s$ is true in $w_2$ and $s$ is the same set in both worlds?

Another way to ask the question is whether the members of a set can differ between possible worlds or whether a set has all its members necessarily.

I came across an argument in some paper not really related to set theory that seemed to presuppose that sets have their members necessarily. But I was not aware of any such principle so far. I suppose it would already help me, if someone knows where such a principle is discussed and could point me towards that.

Comment: A set (in the "current" mathematical sense) is "identified" by its memebers; see [Extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality). Thus, if a set changes its "composition" from a world to another, it is not the "same" set.

Comment: But compare with [Kripke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saul_Kripke#Naming_and_Necessity) 's theory about [names](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rigid-designators/#StaClaKri).

Comment: The axiom of extensionality may still be true in each possible world. If the domain of quantification is relative to the possible world it is at least not inconsistent to assume the the set s is identical between the worlds. I at least think that this is so.

Comment: Maybe relevant : [Modal set-theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813852/modal-set-theory).